# Finding last item of a set of items within a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I've got a collection of items all with a Key and a "sequence" number.  I am trying to find the items with the "last" sequence number for each of the keys...but the sequence numbers are within a "window" (as they are date based).

Example Data

```
Key     Seq     other data.....
___     ___     _________________
ABC     4       
ABC     5
ABC     6
FGH     1
FGH     2
FGH     3
FGH     4
FGH     5
FGH     6
FGH     7
FGH     8
FGH     9
FGH     10
OPQ     6
RST     3
RST     4
```

and I would be looking for the result:

```
ACB     6
FGH     10
OPQ     6
RST     4
```

I can get this by looping through each key one-by-one, but seems there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: Where do you read your data from? Can you bring your data into a List if `Dictionary` or `Tuple`?

Comment: if you use IEnumerable<Class> you can use: collection.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => new MyClass { Key = x.Key, Seq = x.Max(z => z.Seq) });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the items guaranteed to be sorted in the original data?

If so, then you can do this:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => item.Key).Select(group => group.Last());
```

If they can initially be out of order, then this would work:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(item => item.Key)
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(item => item.Seq).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
collection
.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
.Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, MaxSeq = x.Max(e => e.Seq));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by Linq:
This code if you want to select last

```
var result = from data in YourObject
                     group data by data.Key into item
                     select new { Key = item.Key, Seq = item.Last().Seq, OtherDataOjbect= item.Last().OtherDataOjbect };
```

And if you want to select max, Use this:

```
var result = from data in YourObject
                     group data by data.Key into item
                     select new { Key = item.Key, Seq = item.Max(x => x.Seq), obj = item.Single(x => x.Seq == item.Max(z => z.Seq)).obj };
```